# MHT-File is not shown in InternetExplorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, base64, mhtml

I have a mht-File which will not be shown in InternetExplorer 9. I have seen, that the text/html-part is encoded in base64:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Could this be the reason, that IE9 will not be able to show the MHT-File?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet explorer 9 can open such MHT files with no problem.

Here are two files you can test with:

- [Original saved MHT file](http://db.tt/XIcOJzgu) - This file has the HTML encoded as `quoted printable`.
- [Modified saved MHT file](http://db.tt/kLnttwxN) - For this file, I decoded the `quoted printable` HTML and re-encoded it as `base64`.

See if you can open both of those files.

You can also decode the base64 (for example, here: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) and see what HTML it produces.  If the base64-encoded data is corrupt, it may produce bad HTML that the browser cannot display.

---

UPDATE: I looked at the MHT file linked in the comment below.  It does not contain a valid HTML page in it and therefore it cannot be displayed in Internet Explorer.

The original decoded HTML:

```
<P style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt" class=yiv1976172747msonormal><FONT size=3>
<SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: black; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">
My name is Walther </SPAN><SPAN style="COLOR: black"><?xml:namespace prefix = o
ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></SPAN></FONT></P>
<P style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt" class=yiv1976172747msonormal><FONT size=3><SPAN
style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: black; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">I have some
money to invest in your country</SPAN><SPAN style="COLOR: black"><o:p></o:p>
</SPAN></FONT></P>
<P style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt" class=MsoNormal><FONT size=3><SPAN
style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: black; mso-bidi-font-weight: bold">My email
</SPAN><B><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: #ff6600">:</SPAN></B><FONT
face="Times New Roman"> </FONT></FONT><A href="mailto:dipl.george.walther@
hotmail.com"><SPAN style="TEXT-DECORATION: none; text-underline: none"><FONT
size=3 face="Times New Roman">dipl.george.walther@hotmail.com</FONT></SPAN>
</A><B><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: #ff6600"><o:p></o:p></SPAN>
</B></P>
```

When I removed the invalid tags added by Outlook (the `<o:p>` and similar) and added `<html>` and `body` tags around the whole thing, the MHT file opened correctly in Internet Explorer.

In short, Outlook produces bad HTML and Internet Explorer doesn't know how to read it.

Comment: Hi Moshe - this is my file, which I cannot open in IE9: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4701983/contact.mht - It comes from Outlook and can there be shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the `mht` file is downloaded from a web server, the `CONTENT-DISPOSITION` header may be set to `Attachment`, which would prevent it from being viewed in the browser for IE9 or greater. Here is the explanation:

- [How Internet Explorer downloads HTML-files through Download Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2846926)